# Jira to Azure boards migration is not working with Solidify tool

Tags: jira

I'm trying to migrate work items from Jira to Azure boards using the Solidify tool. I'm using Jira on-premises version 8.8.1. I have tried the username (with and without domain) but still getting an unauthorized-401 error.

command:

```
jira-export -u xxxxxx -p xxxxxx --url https://jira url/ --config config-scrum.json --force
```

Error:

```
[E][13.07.18] Unexpected migration error.
[System.AggregateException] System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Response Content: <html>

<head>
    <title>Unauthorized (401)</title>
```

Comment: From you description, your issue is on the first step that exporting Jira issues from Jira queries, so this issue is related to jira and jira-azuredevops-migrator, not Azure Devops. I have modified the tag to help you get appropriate support.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of issue, and I made it work by:

- Replacing the username by the email address of the account I want to use, and;
- Replacing the password by an access token generated on Jira.

See [API tokens](https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/api-tokens-938839638.html).